# Making RESTful requests Cross-Domain in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, cross-domain

I'm trying to find the most convenient, and efficient(i.e. scalable) way to make cross-domain requests in Javascript, that allows use of full HTTP verbs(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) in my requests. Our issue is we have a light weight architecture that allows for data storage and and an API to be distributed across multiple small servers, and to have either one, or two servers providing web services mostly written in pure Javascript.

I want to be able to consume the API from Javascript with the least ugly hack/solution, I've played with JSONP, server side proxying(not sure if scalable?) and iframe proxying, but these all end in needing a special functionality hosted by the API to translate these requests to normal calls. Is there a way for me to get this functionality without annoying work arounds, or am I stuck with one?

(I also looked at postMessage, but its still not fully supported and provides the same issue of not being able to specify the HTTP verb.)

Comment: For cross-domain requests that are interoperable with the most browsers, you will need to use JSONP which it sounds like you're already familiar with.  Are you asking if there's some other magic bullet?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) but the browser support is still fairly limited. MDC has the best [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) covering `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

The basic flow is the browser does a pre-flight OPTIONS request, the server responds with headers allowing access, and the browser makes the full request.

Comment: "Fairly limited support" [being](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing#Browser_support) IE8, FF3.5, Chrome 3, Safari 4, Opera 12, or [>90% of all browsers](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201201-201202-bar) -- in other words, not limited at all.

Comment: Support: 56.29% Partial support: 29.52%. If you don't want to be limited to GET and POST you are stuck with 56% - http://caniuse.com/cors

Comment: That 29% is IE 8 & 9, where you have to use `XDomainRequest` instead of the regular XHR like every other browser.  You're right that it does feature a [limited subset](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) of functionality, but it is better than nothing.  (And another case of IE being IE.)